# How much data can be loaded on a webpage from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, web-applications, plotly

I'm creating a webapp with Dash. I'm adding data to my charts using a Pandas dataframe. The structure is this: i declared the DF and filled it with data from a MongoDB collection using a query.

```
db = client.one
mycol = client['coll']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.mycol.find({})))
```

This is my question: since i have a real-time chart, i will constantly be sending data to my database, so at a certain point this DB will contain a lot of data (i calculated that in one year my collection/table could contain 1M elements), as a result, all this data will have to be stored and charted each second; is this scalable? Will load all that data crash my app or make it extremely heavy to load? If that's the case, how could i avoid it?

Comment: You're right, this is certainly not scalable. you should divide time into windows, and accumulate from a certain date, retire each dataframe after a certain amount of time from memory. and load the next one (that hopefully began ingesting data a couple days earlier)

Comment: I think my DF gets overwritten each time the DB query is processed. It should remove the old data and fill the dataframe with the new data from the database